# excel calculate based on field value

Tags: excel

I would like to calculate average percentage of the applications marked as in use (Yes)

Anyone?

```
    Average Percentage:     
    A       B           C
1   Name    Percentage  In Use
2   Hammer  65%         Yes
3   Fork    77%         Yes
4   Spoon   65%         No
5   Cars    33%         No
6   Wheel   87%         Yes
```

Comment: As a one-time thing or as a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use the built-in `AVERAGEIF()`.

```
=AVERAGEIF($C$2:$C$6,"Yes",$B$2:$B$6)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time solution:

- Mark all the values from A1 to C6.
- Go to *Filter and Sort* and select *Sort*
- In C1 there will now be a dropdown with 3 checkboxes: All, Yes, No,
  Empty. Check the Yes box
- Now select all values in coumn B.
- Then in the little tool square thing. (Don't know what its called)
  select Totals and Avarage.

The average percentage of all rows marked Yes wil now be calculated.

A Macro solution:

```
Sub avarage()
    Range("A2:C6").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$C$6").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Yes"
    Range("B7").FormulaR1C1 = "=MIDDEL(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"
    Range("B7").Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With classical and useful functions :

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$6;"=Yes";$B$2:$B$6)/COUNTIF($C$2:$C$6;"=Yes")
```

Or with `SUMPRODUCT` (awesome function) :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$6="Yes")*($B$2:$B$6))/SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$6="Yes")*1)
```